# ASP.NET Div Layout - CSS Sticky Footer

Tags: html, css, asp.net, master-pages, footer

I'll apologize first because I understand that this has been asked a zillion times, but I've tried everything I've found to no avail. :(

FYI: I am attempting to create an ASP.NET web app using Master Page.  All HTML code below is from my MP.

I have 3 questions:

1. How the heck do I make my footer stick (my failed code will be below)?
2. In the setup below, I have nested divs inside the Header/Content, etc. I am assuming that doesn't affect my epic journey toward sticking the footer to the bottom?
3. Lastly, I have the (form) tag immediately after my (body) tags. I know other folks have mentioned that they felt as though there was an issue.  I, too, feel like it messes with my ability to sticky my footer... but maybe this is an irrational fear emerging from my Noob instincts... lol.

Thank you in advance for taking the time to help me!!

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10pt;
  background-color: #F2FDFF;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
a {
  outline: none;
}
#wholePg {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#divNav-cont {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}
#divNav {
  background-color: #DBDBDB;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  font: 0/0a;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 25px 25px;
}
#divBody {
  width: 98%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-top: 110px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
#divFooter {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 0px;
  background-color: #DBDBDB;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <form runat="server">
    <div id="wholePg">

      <%--Navigation--%>
        <div id="divNav-cont">
          <div id="divNav">
            <div id="imgNav">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <%--Body: Left and Right--%>
          <div id="divBody">
            <div id="leftContainer" class="bodyWidth196px">
              <div class="mainHeader">
                <p>Left</p>
              </div>
              <div class="mainBody overflowYhidden
                                overflowXhidden bodyWidth196px
                                borderBottomCurved height85percent">
                <p>
                  Blah blah etc.
                </p>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="LeftContentPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
                <br />
                <br />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div id="rightContainer" class="bodyWidth580px">
              <div class="mainHeader">RIGHT</div>
              <div class="mainBody bodyWidth580px borderBottomCurved">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="BodyContentPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
                <br />
                <br />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <%--Footer--%>
            <div id="divFooter" class="center">
              <br />Blabbity boo dee dah.

            </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the usual HTML solution to implement a sticky footer:

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/html-code.html

```
html, body {height: 100%;}

#wrap {min-height: 100%;}

#main {overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 180px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */

#footer {position: relative;
    margin-top: -180px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 180px;
    clear:both;} 

/*Opera Fix*/
body:before {/* thanks to Maleika (Kohoutec)*/
content:"";
height:100%;
float:left;
width:0;
margin-top:-32767px;/* thank you Erik J - negate effect of float*/
}
```

It took me a long time to figure out how to make this work with ASPNET and master pages. The trick is to add the form tag to the html, body {...} rule as follows:

```
html, body, form {height: 100%;}
```

So, your main layout divs should have the following pattern:

```
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <div id="wrap">
            <div id="main">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Mine is still not working. :( I will try again and maybe just build out from scratch to see if I can get it to go properly (and then add in the stuff I have) - hopefully I'll figure out what's breaking it.  Thank you for your response, though!!  :)